Has anyone else experienced the: 'NX The externalDependency 'webpack-cli' for 'app' could not be found' error?
I have been using @nx v18.1.2 for a while now (mostly experimenting at the moment), but every once in a while, I will see the following error message when building nestjs or angular apps in particular:
'NX The externalDependency 'webpack-cli' for 'app' could not be found'
It seems to occur when I have added a new dependency to the root package.json. I am not understanding why this happens in the first place to have insight into how to fix this properly.
I have removed node_modules, reinstalled @nx/webpack and webpack-cli via npm, but I am not certain what the real solution is as these don't always work.

UPDATE: Suddenly occurred to me to look to see if NX stores any caching files for its internal purposes. Indeed, it does :) Removing the .nx/ folder solved the problem for me. However, I hope NRWL can reproduce the issue to track the true source of the problem. Strange to me every time this happens, it is the webpack-cli dependency that cannot be found.

We're facing it now. Cleared node_modules, pnpm-lock, .nx, cache, dist. Basically g to our project clear. Still getting this error.

See potential answer below, maybe related to PNPM.

Looks like this is currently an issue with PNPM 9. This link suggests downgrading to version 8 helps: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/22871#issuecomment-2063655570
